# Gradle build failed, keystore.properties not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to open this GitHub project with Android Studio
https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar

But sync failed because the system cannot find keystore.properties file.

I tried some solutions I found at other threads by commenting out release line in build.gradle, but it didnt work.

```
signingConfigs {
//        release {
//            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
//            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
//            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
//            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
```

I could be commenting out the wrong parts or there are other reasons.
Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the same script, you have to create a `keystore.properties` in the root of your project with your values:

```
storePassword=123456
keyPassword=abcdef
keyAlias=myAlias
storeFile=../keystore.jks
```

You can find some [tips here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-apk).

Otherwise you can have many options to configure the signing configs.
For example:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("release.keystore")
            storePassword "******"
            keyAlias "******"
            keyPassword "******"
        }
    }
```

Other info in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I followed your instruction. It didnt work at first, and I made some minor adjustment here and there and somehow it worked. So still a bit confused but Thank you!